# Dealing with timezone naive datetimes in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have some JSON data that contains timezone naive dates.

```
["2014-03-07T09:04:26.943", "2014-03-06T20:35:21.937", "2014-02-25T12:39:44"]
```

I read this data using pandas.read_json, and it treats it as an object column.

I know the data is in the Pacific timezone, NOT UTC.

Is there a vectorized way to convert this to a np.datetime64 column? Currently, I'm doing:

```
def _parse_datetime(dt_string):
    # We are provided timezone naive data that is in Pacific time. Convert it to UTC.
    timestamp = pd.Timestamp(dt_string, tz="US/Pacific")
    if pd.isnull(timestamp):
        return pd.NaT
    return np.datetime64(timestamp)

data.apply(_parse_datetime)
```

which is really slow for a large amount of data

UPDATE:

By specifying convert_dates, I can coerce the data to datetime. However, while attempting to localize, I get errors:

```
>>> dates = """["2014-03-07T09:04:26.943", "2014-03-06T20:35:21.937", "2014-02-25T12:39:44"]""" 
>>> baz = pd.read_json(dates, convert_dates=[0])[0]
>>> baz.tz_localize('US/Pacific')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/abeer/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3494, in tz_localize
ax_name)
TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

More generically, I'm trying to do this for a column in a dataframe, so I can't modify the index.

Comment: does setting the `convert_dates` kwarg to the column with the date values help read the values as dates initially?

Answer (score 1):

Use the convert_dates option to specify the columns, or using the series type option should convert automatically.

```
>>> pd.read_json(dates, convert_dates=[0])[0]
0   2014-03-07 09:04:26.943000
1   2014-03-06 20:35:21.937000
2          2014-02-25 12:39:44
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> pd.read_json(dates, typ='series')
0   2014-03-07 09:04:26.943000
1   2014-03-06 20:35:21.937000
2          2014-02-25 12:39:44
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

From there you can use *tz_localize* on the timestamps.  Assuming this is too slow...

```
baz.apply(lambda ts: ts.tz_localize('US/Pacific'))
```

The inlined tz_localize works on the index (not the values):

```
>>> pd.Series(index=baz).tz_localize('US/Pacific')
0
2014-03-07 09:04:26.943000-08:00   NaN
2014-03-06 20:35:21.937000-08:00   NaN
2014-02-25 12:39:44-08:00          NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, passing convert_dates helps by parsing the dates correctly. However, I still can't use tz_localize in an unvectorized fashion. I updated the question with more details.